# Does the word "constant" have two meanings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Today I learned about the ruby `constantize` method that, when called on a string, looks for any class or module with the same name, and sets it to be that class or module.

My understanding of the word 'constant' has always been 'a variable that you cannot change once you have initialized it.' Is there another definition of 'constant' that means 'a class or a module?'

Or am I misunderstanding `constantize` completely?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, things that begin with a Capital letter are constants. They may not be assigned in dynamic code, such as inside a method, that might be called twice. (You get a nasty warning when such code evaluates twice anyway, such as due to eager `load`ing...)

So a `class Foo` assigns a constant, Foo, whose value is a class.